# Subject of gerund phrase

Tags: gerunds, subjects, present-participles

> *Me getting a hangover is nothing like her getting a hangover.*

-

> *I'd rather contemplate you singing than him singing.*

Is this grammatically correct?

Comment: This is a new take for me on the acc-ing issue. I've found 'Him getting drunk was fine, but ...' on the internet, and 'I'd rather contemplate you singing / your singing' are both well known and acceptable. I can't see why, if 'I don't like you getting a hangover' is acceptable, 'You getting a hangover is something I don't like' shouldn't be.

Comment: In a formal register I would say *My getting a hangover is nothing like her getting a hangover*, and *I'd rather contemplate your singing, than his singing*. But in many everyday situations, especially if I was hung over at the time, talking to my wife across the breakfast table, I might well adopt the style you have presented.

Comment: @tchrist But that doesn't address the acceptability of acc-ing structures as subject. At least there isn't the 'Me as part of a subject?' issue with  'She doesn't like me getting a hangover'.

Comment: AWS2 'I'd rather contemplate you singing' is at least as acceptable as 'I'd rather contemplate your singing' in any register.

Comment: Indeed, "contemplate you singing" is contemplating the **person** and "contemplate your singing" is contemplating the **singing**. Similarly "Me getting a hangover" emphasises "me" and "My getting a hangover" emphasises the process of the hangover.

Comment: May I thank OP for their question, leading to Greg Lee's discovery (again, thanks to him) of the excellent treatment by Cornilescu dealing with (amongst other related points) the possibility / frequency of the use of Acc-ing structures in subject position.

Comment: @Andrew Leach 'Her getting a hangover' emphasises the quirkiness of English.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about "correct", but they're grammatical.  They're called accusative-ing or ACC-ing complements (by analogy to possessive-ing or POSS-ing complements, with which they seem to alternate).

Comment: Have you an authority showing an ACC-ing structure being used as the subject of a sentence?

Comment: No, @EdwinAshworth, I don't have an authority (other than me).

Comment: I think it's obvious that ACC-ing constructions as subjects are grammatical, but here I found something in print: http://ebooks.unibuc.ro/filologie/cornilescu/15.pdf.  See item (46).

Comment: Thank you: a valuable resource. Alexandra Cornilescu's '2.1. Comparing the frequency of various types of complements subjects, Close (1972) notices that Poss-ing and Acc-ing complements “seem to be less frequent _as subjects_, at least in the spoken language”. When a full ing complement is, nevertheless, used as a subject, _Poss-ing appears to be the more natural construction_. **Acc-ing constructions in subject position are also possible, however.** ...   Acc-ing. e. Millie flirting with Christopher was one good thing.' [emphasis mine] is highly relevant.