# Should we put apostrophe after John to make it a Possesive Gerund?

Tags: grammar

1)John trying to tell everybody what he thought annoyed me.

2)George ringing me up at three o'clock in the morning to tell me he was in love again didn't please me.

I have read the above two sentences from a grammar book.
I am wondering if we should put a apostrophe right after John and George to make it a possessive gerund.

Does anyone think that too?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["...his parents' dream of \*him\* achieving a Cambridge degree." What is the function of "him" here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94235/his-parents-dream-of-him-achieving-a-cambridge-degree-what-is-the-funct) Or this: [When is a gerund supposed to be preceded by a possessive adjective/determiner?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/when-is-a-gerund-supposed-to-be-preceded-by-a-possessive-adjective-determiner) ...

Comment: Or, for use as subject (John/John's trying to tell everybody what he thought) [subject of gerund phrase](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226187/subject-of-gerund-phrase/226193#226193)?

Comment: "John's trying to tell everybody what he thought ..." is horribly slow in showing it is not parsed as "John is trying to ..."

Comment: I read sentence #1 as: John, *trying to tell everybody what he thought*, annoyed me. For me, *John's trying* is too precious, and I'd reword it.

Comment: You mean apostrophe _s_. The subjects here can be plain case "John" / "George" or genitive "John's" / "George's". It's a free choice, though the genitive is somewhat formal. Note that personal pronouns can be either accusative or genitive: "His/him trying to tell everybody what he thought annoyed me"

Comment: @BillJ Thanks for your explanation. Are you saying that it 's just informal to write it without apostrophe? Since I have bumped into a lesson from engvid talking about this(https://www.engvid.com/possessive-gerunds/). He purposely highlighted that it should be "Miguel's complaining". So, my question is -adding in apostrophe is just being formal?

Comment: Yes, "Miguel's complaining" and "Miguel complaining" are both OK. the former (with the apostrophe added) being more formal.